# how to edit/rename/remove keys and values in multiple json files from aws s3 in python

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, key, boto3

I have JSON files in a folder and (sub folders: Folder A has sub folder B and C and so on) within AWS S3 bucket and I would like to change the name of the keys of all the JSON files and remove some keys & values.
At first, I tried to get the list of the files within my folder A as:

```py
def get_s3_list(bucket, prefix):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")    
    objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    obj_list = [lc['Key'] for lc in objects['Contents']]
    return obj_list
s3_list = get_s3_list('bucket', 'prefix')
full_s3_list = [ll.split('/') for ll in s3_list]

json_list_files = []
for sub_list in full_s3_list:
     for sb in sub_list:
          if sb.endswith('.json') or sb.endswith('.JSON'):
              json_list_files.append(sub_list)
```

Then, I want to rename some of the keys in each json file. For instance one json file looks like:

```
{
   "name": "Apple",
   "type": "sweet",
   "size": "12",
   "country": "Germany",
   "path": "s1",
   "other info": "not known",
}
```

For all the files, I want to rename the keys and remove some keys & values such as to get

```
{
   "name of fruit": "Apple",
   "taste": "sweet",
   "size": "12",
   "path_id": "s1",

}
```

I know how to change only one key name from one file but I cannot figure out how to apply that for all the files and for more than one key name. I have tried this but I cannot get what I want at the end:

```py
new_names = { 'name'            : 'name of fruit' ,
              'type'      : 'taste' ,
              'size'        : 'size', 
              'path'       : 'path_id'
              }


for row in json_list_files:
  for k, v in new_names.items():
    for old_name in row:
      if k == old_name:
        row[v] = row.pop(old_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first download the contents of the s3 bucket and then recursively go through the JSON files and modify them using a JSON processor like `jq`. After that is done, you can run the `aws s3 sync` command so that the modified files are uploaded to the bucket.

Comment: thanks. do you know whether is there any way for modifying the files without downloading the contents? @RVKarmani

Comment: I don't think so. There are tools which provide a GUI for S3 bucket but in the end, they too download the files internally.

Comment: Thanks again, I also would like to ask when you say 'download the contents of the s3 bucket', do you mean download all the folders with the json files in it? or downloading contents has a specific way in here? sorry I am not familiar with aws?

Comment: You can control the files you are downloading with `s3 cp` like downloading only JSON files with `--include` and `--exclude` flags.

Comment: oh then can I upload them back to their specific sub folders in that bucket?if I can, what I should use to do that?

Comment: You could first download the contents with `aws s3 cp` with --exclude="*" and --include="*.json" recursively. After this, you could run a python script to make the necessary JSON changes. Afterward, you can run `aws s3 sync` so that the modified files are uploaded to the bucket. The directory structure is maintained during cp and sync will take care of the file paths.